# Transient power supply with LM317 and LM2576

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi, lm317, failure

I have a power supply to power an 8W LED board and a Raspberry Pi.

[image]

I have used a 24VAC (12-0-12V) 2A transformer to feed the bridge. I have also used a LM317 to provide a voltage of approximately 15.8V for the LEDs.  The output is also used by the LM2576 to provide the 5V for the RPi. The V+ socket is connected to the LED PCB through a switch and the return to ground is an unbroken connection. The Rpi is always ON. The LEDs consume 500mA at 15.8V and the RPi consumes a maximum of less than 1A at 5V (measured using an ammeter.)

When I power ON, with the switch connecting power to the LEDs (full load,) the circuit works without a problem. However, when I switch off the LEDs after power ON, soon after a few seconds the RPi also goes down. The 5V output is now 2.3V and not sufficient for the RPi. The V+ reads 2.8V to 3.3V.
Even if I power on without the switch connecting power to the LEDs, the RPi soon shutdowns due to low voltage.

This is really puzzling for me. How can a power supply work fine at full load but fail at lesser loads? Has anyone had such issues before and if so how did you solve it?

Comment: I suspect that C2, 1000 µF may be involved. It shouldn't be there as the regulator should handle output fluctuations. A 100 nF would be more appropriate. However, I can't explain the latch-up on sudden reduction of load.

Comment: Inductance in the LED load? Switching off an inductive load without a flyback diode could cause a transient.

Comment: You said the LEDs are connected to the output from the linear regulator, but in your schematic you have it on the output from the LM2576. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Transistor C2 is usually advisable, although 1000 uF is probably excessive. The LM317 is stable without an output cap, but will be more stable with one and also will improve transient response.

Comment: Have you tried connecting input of LM2576 to the output of your bridge?  Application note shows input of 55V unregulated.

Comment: Come back and include V+ measurements with Vin in your question. and report if anything is hot.  Vin no load is expected to rise 50%

Comment: @awjlogan: I've just checked the [TI LM317 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) and the examples all have a 1 µF on the output.

Comment: basically LM317 has a Darlington emitter Follower output and driving a huge cap invites issues.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, and very rarely with no output cap. As Tony said, 1000 uF is inviting problems, exacerbated with low ESR caps.

Comment: i bet that the LEDs pull down the voltage that's fed to the 5v regulator. When you stop the load, the input voltage climbs, the difference turns to heat, and within a short time overheats the 5v regulator, which probably shuts itself down. is it really hot?

Comment: Both the regulators are hot and what value should the capacitors be given that the load is reasonable large?

Comment: @hp07 dandavis's suggestion seems reasonable. I would move the 1000 uF cap on the output of the LM317 to just after the bridge (giving you 2000 uF total) and put a 47-100 uF cap in its place. Try that, and see! Other question, do you even need to use the LM317, or would your LED string be ok with 17V?

Comment: Did you connect the two 12V windings of the transformer in series or parallel? In other words, are you feeding your circuit 12VAC or 24VAC?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the buck converter output to C1, not to the output of LM317. This will reduce current through LM317 and reduce power wasted as head in LM317 too.

Also add ceramic decoupling caps on the input of the buck converter. Something like two 1-10µF MLCCs of appropriate voltage, placed and routed for low inductance. You also need at least one MLCC on the output, like 10µF 6.3V.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your LM317 is regulating from 24V down to 16V, that is 8V drop. And you are drawing 1.5A. So regulator has to dissipate 12W of heat. You must use proper heatsink. The same applies to your buck convertor.

Comment: Nope, he's paralleling the transformer outputs, so only 17V down to 15.8 V. A bit low for regulation but doesn't account for the observed behaviour.

Comment: @awjlogan where did you take 17V from? You mean 12V * 1.41? Are you sure you are able to draw 1.5A @ 16V DC from 2A @ 12V AC? You want to draw 26W from 24W source? There is a problem in design then. Not mentioning that you need like 2V voltage drop.

Comment: OP has stated that the RPi is "less than 1 A", but there's no exact figure so I don't think we're breaking energy conservation here :) The 17 V is rectified (as you said) but there's also the 1.4 V voltage drop in the bridge. Everything is very close to current/voltage/heat limits, so I think the system is not well designed.

Comment: @awjlogan _"Nope, he's paralleling the transformer outputs ..."_ - Nowhere do I see the OP stating that fact, so you cannot assume that. It needs verification.

Comment: @marcelm Agreed, but if it wasn't parallel it wouldn't work at all, given the power dissipation in the LM317. But yes, does need verification.

Comment: Heating is clearly not an issue as the system works continuously at full load for more than an hour. The issue is only when it is at partial load on power up or when I go from full load to partial load by switching off the LEDs. Thats why its puzzling for me.

Comment: @hp07 add oscilloscope readings at 5V rail.

Comment: I have decided to reduce my problem by not cascading the supplies and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Put the lm317's output on a scope. That chip is known for being a little "ringy" under transient loads, and with that 1000 uF on the output it could be going unstable.